# informed date field example? & more documentation

Tags: reactjs, forms

Informed is a new better version of react-form.
I am looking for a date field example
and any documentation other than the formal website.

Comment: No `informed` tag is available for now, and no `react-form` tag too.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. Even in `react-form` docs, you have to do implementation yourself using HOCs and validation.
To implement this date field take a look at [CustomInput doc and example](https://joepuzzo.github.io/informed/?selectedKind=CustomInputs&selectedStory=Creating%20Custom%20Inputs&full=0&addons=0&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=REACT_STORYBOOK%2Freadme%2Fpanel) and use custom validation rules and masks for date to make your component `InformedField`.